# Echo is off in script

Tags: batch-file

I have a quite extensive batch file for swapping project files around and includes a few menu's and clearscreen commands. I have included the command - @Echo off to avoid all commands being output.  The batch file works fine except it outputs the statement "Echo is off" when I refresh the screen for a new menu.  Is there any way to stop the "Echo is off" statement?

Comment: You can stop a output by using >nul

Comment: rather you have `echo %variable%` somewhere and variable is not defined.

Comment: I am not actually attempting to stop a certain output. The batch file is not outputting commands and outputting everything I want except it is outputting one thing extra - the "Echo is off." line when the screen refreshes after a clear screen.  How do I stop the "Echo is off" from being output?

Answer (score 2):

Look for a line that has echo and either nothing after it or a variable that is empty.

This is good to echo a blank line

```
echo(
```

and similarly this will echo a blank line and not a "echo is off" error when the variable is empty.

```
echo(%variable%
```

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` statement is question is attempting to echo a variable which is not set.

The easy way is to replace `echo %var%` with `echo(%var%`